# Cannot install modules using pip - it gives an error

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, pygame, python-3.9

I uninstalled Python 3.8 and then installed Python 3.9.

Now, when I try to install any module using pip:

```
pip install pygame
```

It shows this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\acer\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s3fy0toj\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Acer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s3fy0toj\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-lgmfm8yh'
         cwd: C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s3fy0toj\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s3fy0toj\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s3fy0toj\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s3fy0toj\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s3fy0toj\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried uninstalling and installing Python again, but still no luck. I had no problem like this when I was using Python 3.8

When I tried installing Django, it worked but then I tried installing Pandas and it did not work.

Please help.

Comment: What pip command you entered ?

Comment: I entered `pip install pygame`

Comment: Instead of pasting just the error, consider posting what command you actually ran.

Comment: @Pythony , Have you done any setting of file path/directory to Environment variables when you installed python 3.8? or you just clicked the **Add to path** on the installation process?

Comment: @Ice Bear, , I don't remember but when I check environment variable, there is no environment variable of python 3.8

Comment: Oh.. okay so when you check on the Environment variable of your computer there is no path there of the pip?

Comment: @Ice Bear, No..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some compatibility issues with python3.9.

For more information,you can check this link.

https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2145

Comment: It should work.For the time being use python 3.8 only.

Comment: So there's no way I could use it in Python 3.9

Comment: Thanks for your help, I uninstalled Python 3.9 and reinstalled Python 3.8 and it worked!